# Spring routing gets 404 error because of invalid routing

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

For an assignment i'm practising Java's Spring MVC for creating a web application. I've build this whole project in the IDE Intellij Ultimate 2016.2.5.

I've created a Maven project for this, imported the correct and asked dependencies for this and build it.

The IDE build the following directory structure:

```
├───src
│   └───bas
│       └───animalkingdom
│           ├───config
│           ├───controllers
├───test
│   └───bas
│       └───animalkingdom
└───web
    ├───META-INF
    ├───resources
    └───WEB-INF
        └───pages
```

The `config` package is where my configuration class is, extending from WebMvcConfigurerAdapter:

package bas.animalkingdom.config;

```
import ...

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("bas.animalkingdom")
@EnableWebMvc
public class Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {           registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```

I thought the `@ComponentScan` had to point to the main source directory where all your source files are.

I was told that I also need a class extending from the `WebApplicationInitializer`. I got this one from my school

```
package bas.animalkingdom.config;

import ...

public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(Config.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }
}
```

This one is also in the `config` package.

The Config class is set as the `Spring Application Context` in the project structure settings in my IDE.

---

In the root directory is the `web` folder. In the folder `WEB-INF` is a empty `web.xml` file, which I was told I didn't need because the settings would be loaded via the configuration class. It looks like this:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

</web-app>
```

In the root directory of the `web` folder is a `index.jsp` file.

In the `bas.animalkingdom.controllers` package are my controllers. For testing purposing, I only created one:

```
package bas.animalkingdom.controllers;

import ...

@Controller("AnimalC")
public class AnimalController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/animals", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAnimals(ModelMap modelMap) {
        Animal animal = new AfricanElephant(new Male(), "Body Covering", "Ename", " acolor", 123, 321);
        modelMap.put("animal", animal);
        return "animals";
    }
}
```

With this controller I expected that I can go to the `localhost/animals` URL, and that it would load up the `animals.jsp` file located in my `web\WEB-INF\pages\` package.

My code has no compile errors in it.

When I run my TomCat server, and open my browser to go to the localhost with the corresponding host, the index.jsp file just loads with no problem. This file is located in the `web\` package.

When I go to the `localhost:(port)/animals`, I just get a 404 page, with the message that the page could not be found.

What does cause this? I've defined the controller which sets that route right?

Also, when looking up other Spring MVC tutorials, they all use a different packaging, does this work as well?

Comment: For starters remove your `web.xml` you don't need it and it currently prevents the `WebInitializer` from doing its work.

Comment: Don't you need to return `pages/animals` in your controller?

Comment: @OlarAndrei Why is that?

Comment: Well, when I used Spring + Thymeleaf, I used to hold my templates under src/main/resources where a another folder holding all the templates was added to the classpath. If it is similar to what I have done, when you have another folder inside, like he has the `WEB-INF/pages` you also have to specify that folder, in this case `pages` in your controller return statement. Because it looks by default in the root template folder, which could be just`WEB-INF` and does not find any `animals.html` or whatever insinde. I just think, that's why I've asked. And, since is a 404, is a Client-Side Error

Comment: @OlarAndrei I already tried the "common" maven packaging structure, this caused the same problem. I just tried that, but that also did not work..

Comment: @Bas Instead of `resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");` I have used `resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/WEB-INF/pages/");` and I do not think you have to specify the `WEB-INF` folder. `resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/pages/");` should be enough. Try like that. If it does not work check if your `pages` folder is on the `classpath`

Comment: @OlarAndrei That did not work unfortunately, how can I check the `classpath` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your java classes and jsps are fine, problem is your module structure. There are basically 2 approaches to your problem, the conventional (recommended) and unconventional way. Let's start with the unconventional way, which is quicker and not recommended:

**A.** The Unconventional:

Add to your maven-war-plugin, the warSourceDirectory tag as shown below:

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/web</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The disadvantage of using this approach is that other plugins may give you unexpected problems down the road, for example the maven-jetty-plugin will not run out of the box with this approach. It defaults to looking in src/main/webapp, although it is configurable. Maven life is easier if you follow the conventional approach.

**B.** Conventional Approach:

The solution lies in having a conventional maven structure for your module, make sure to do the following:

1. Delete Your web.xml file. If maven package failed because of missing web.xml file, add the below plugin in the **build** section of your pom.xml :

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.0.0</version>
       <configuration>
           <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```
2. Create folder structure **/src/main/java** and put all your java packages into this **java directory**. If your packages are not formatted properly, you can right click folder **java** and go to Mark Directory as -> Source Root.
3. Create folder structure **/src/test/java** and put all your test packages in the java directory.
4. Create a folder structure **/src/main/webapp** and put all the contents of folder **web** into the **webapp** directory.

After doing this you can test your application. You can try using jetty plugin to deploy your web app with the below configuration:

```
    <build>
    <finalName>spring-mvc</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.11.v20150529</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                </webApp>
                <httpConnector>
                    <port>8080</port>
                </httpConnector>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: This is an ok solution, but you shouldn't mark your directories as source or test within the IDE. You should complete the changes as outlined above, then reimport the project directly from the pom.xml file. This should refresh all your paths and configure the project correctly.

Comment: @TauraiNyamakura I did not even have that plugin yet, could that have been a problem?

Comment: @Bas if you are packaging your module as a war it's best to have the "maven-war-plugin" plugin in your build section. As for the "jetty-maven-plugin", you can remove it from the build section if you are not using it. Jetty plugin is recommended only for development phase testing, you can use it if you quickly want to test your module using : mvn jetty:run (to start jetty and deploy your module)

Comment: @TauraiNyamakura Thank you for this answer! it definitly worked. One more question though, is it actually "needed" to have the same "standard" directory structure belonging to a maven project for this to work?

Comment: Yes it's actually needed to have this standard directory structure for maven, unless if you want to change the pom directory settings on your own.

Comment: @TauraiNyamakura What do you mean changing the directory settings? Is it not "needed" to have this structure for it to work?

Comment: It's really necessary to stick to maven standard structure. I mean changing maven directory structure in the Pom.xml file like option A in the above answer.